# How do I import a raw AES key to a JCEKS keystore?

Tags: security, java, aes

I have some test data that is encrypted with 256 bit AES. The customer supplied the key as a 256 bit file. The application uses a java key store for decryption keys. The keytool options I've found only support generating new keys or importing them from another store. Is there any way to get this key in the store using keytool?

Comment: Related question on Stack Overflow: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27355827/import-symmetric-key-in-java-keystore-with-command-line

Answer (score 1):

Looks like this isn't an option with keytool. But there is another program that can do it at http://code.google.com/p/keytool-iui